# Custom Tabs shared with all Signers in DocuSign

Tags: docusignapi

I have a template. I have three signers. I want to embed this on my VueJS app. I will create the envlope and send it to DocuSign. All three signers need to see the same PDF embed with all the values. How do I achieve this. When I add a field in Custom Fields, it has only one of the signers attached. I am not sure what Merge Fields are, but when I tried to create one of them, the field just goes back to Custom Fields. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to add some data to your document. You can do that by still using the template and just updating the document itself before you send it.

Alternatively, if the 3 signers sign consecutively (not concurrently) then by adding a field to the first one - all future recipients will also see that field.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yeah, I am trying to pass the values from NodeJS and the value should be visible to all signers. So I should be adding custom Fields, right?

Comment: You can, you don't have to. You can pass values to tabs without making them custom fields. If you have 3 signers, what are the routing order number you are using? you would have to use 1,2, 3 so that they sign in order and add your value to the first signer

Comment: you can fill the value from Node.js this way - https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-node-auth-code-grant/blob/master/lib/examples/eg017SetTemplateTabValues.js

Comment: Adding value to the first signer worked. I see them on the following signers. I am not sure if my client would like that. Is there a way I can achieve this without assigning orders. My client is trying to get signs from three people in one sitting (in-person).

Comment: You can do that by updating the actual document, not using fields. You can still use a template and just dynamically, in your code, update the document to be signed before it's sent out...

Comment: I am assuming that you are suggesting to change the PDF, right? How do I update the PDF document what I have already uploaded to the template

Comment: There are a couple of ways to do that. The recommended approach is to use composite templates. Here is Node.js code example for that - https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-node-auth-code-grant/blob/master/lib/examples/eg013AddDocToTemplate.js

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I won't be able to add another document to the already embeded PDF, my client has to fill in blanks in the original PDF before signing. So customFields would be the way to do it, right?

I have come to a point where I am intergrating the requestView url into a simple iframe. Even thought I set the first signer's email for the requestView, the customFields I sent earlier don't show up. Do you know why?

Comment: ~~~
let viewRequest = await makeRecipientViewRequest({
  "dsReturnUrl": '',
  "signerEmail": 'one@email.com', // same email as first signer
  "signerName": 'Siva Agent',
  // "signerClientId": '',
  "dsPingUrl": 'https://example.com'
 })

 let createView = await envelopesApi.createRecipientView(
  payload.accountId, envelopeId,{recipientViewRequest: viewRequest})
  .then(res => {
   console.log('createView res', res)
  })
  .catch(err => {
   console.log(err.response.error);
  });
~~~

Comment: you don't have to add it, you can replace it, if you specify the same documentId, it will replace it.

Comment: I have come to a point where I am intergrating the requestView url into a simple iframe. Even thought I set the first signer's email for the requestView, the customFields I sent earlier don't show up. Do you know why?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are doing exactly .Might need to see your code. Would recommend posting a separate question

Comment: Thank you. I will post another question with the code.